# Obtaining a plain char* from a string in D?

Tags: string, d

I'm having an absolute hell of a time trying to figure out how to get a plain, mutable C string (a char*) from a D string (a immutable(char)[]) to that I can pass the character data to legacy C code. toStringz doesn't work, as I get an error saying that I "cannot implicitly convert expression (toStringz(this.fileName())) of type immutable(char)* to char*". Do I need to recreate a new, mutable array of char and copy the characters over?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can change the header of the D interface of that legacy C code, ***and*** you are sure that legacy C code will not modify the string, you could make it accept a `const(char)*`, e.g.

```c
char* strncpy(char* dest, const(char)* src, size_t count);
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I'm genuinely confused at why your answer has so many upvotes... didn't the OP mention he wants a *mutable* string?

Comment: @Mehrdad, This has been getting upvotes because the OP probably doesn't need a mutable string. It would have been good to include how to get an mutable string though.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, it's not pretty, because the result is immutable.

*This is why I always return a **mutable** copy of new arrays in my code. There's no point in making them immutable.*

Solutions:

You could just do

```
char[] buffer = (myString ~ '\0').dup; //Concatenate a null terminator, then dup
```

then use `buffer.ptr` as the pointer.

#### However:

This *wastes* a string. A better approach might be:

```
char[] buffer = myString.dup;
buffer ~= '\0'; //Hopefully this doesn't reallocate
```

and using `buffer.ptr` afterwards.

---

Another solution is to use a method like this one:

```
char* toStringz(in char[] s)
{
    string result;
    if (s.length > 0 && s[$ - 1] == '\0') //Is it null-terminated?
    { result = s.dup; }
    else { result = new char[s.length + 1]; result[0 .. s.length][] = s[]; }
    return result.ptr;
}
```

This one is the most efficient but also the longest.

(**Edit**: Whoops, I had a typo in the `if`; fixed it.)

Comment: wouldn't it be better to do `char[] buffer = (myString.dup ~ '\0')` first dup the string and then append `\0` so it won't realloc twice (once for the null concat and once for the dup)

Comment: @ratchetfreak: It would still realloc twice though.

Comment: well if the compiler can optimize it, it won't. but `char[] buffer = (myString[] ~ '\0')`;` will only realloc once

Comment: @ratchet: Yeah but you can't depend on the compiler optimizing that.

Comment: This will work, but if the receiving code doesn't actual need to mutate anything, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass a mutable `char*` to a C function, you're going to need to allocate a mutable `char[]`. `string` isn't going to work, because it's immutable(char)[]. You *can't* alter immutable variables, so there is no way to pass a `string` to a function (C or otherwise) which needs to alter its elements.

So, if you have a `string`, and you need to pass it to a function which takes a `char[]`, then you can use `to!(char[])` or `dup` and get a mutable copy of it. In addition, if you want to pass it to a C function, you're going to need to append a `'\0'` to it so that it's zero-terminated. The easiest way to do that is just to do `~= '\0'` on the `char[]`, but the more efficient way would probably be to do something like this:

```
auto cstring = new char[](str.length + 1);
cstring[0 .. str.length] = str[];
cstring[$ - 1] = '\0';
```

In either case, you then pass `cstring.ptr` to the C function that you're calling.

If you *know* that the C function that you're calling isn't going to alter the string, then you can either do as [KennyTM suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393774/obtaining-a-plain-char-from-a-string-in-d/6394665#6394665) and alter the C function's signature in D to take a `const(char)*`, or you can cast the string. e.g.

```
auto cstring = toStringz(str);
cfunc(cast(char*)cstring.ptr);
```

Altering the C function's signature would be more correct and less error-prone though.

It sounds like we may be altering `std.conv.to` to be smart enough to turn strings into zero-terminated strings when cast to `char*`, `const(char)*`, etc. So, once that's done, getting a zero-terminated mutable string should be easier, but for the moment, you pretty much just need to copy the string and append a `'\0'` to it so that it's zero-terminated. But regardless, you're never going to be able to pass a `string` to a C function which needs to modify it, because a `string` can't be mutated.

Answer (score 1):

Without any context on which function you're calling it's hard to say what is the right solution.

Typically, if the C function wants to modify or write to the string it probably expects you to provide a buffer and a length. Usually what I do is:

Allocate a buffer:

```
auto buffer = new char[](256);  // your own length instead of 256 here
```

And call the C function:

```
CWriteString(buffer.ptr, buffer.length);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try the following :

char a[]="abc";

char *p=a;

Now you can pass pointer 'p' to the array in any function.

Hope it works.