# How Do I Pass Strings Between D and C++?

Tags: c++, string, d

I tried adapting this answer...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26924384/105539

...so that I passed a C++ string into D and then return it with "-response" back, but it fails to compile the D file:

```
// dtest.d
extern (C++) string dfunc(string s) {
        return s ~ "response";
}

$ dmd -c dtest.d
Error: Internal Compiler Error: unsupported type string

dmd: cppmangle.c:576: virtual void CppMangleVisitor::visit(Type*): Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Then, I don't know how to compose the C++ file to make it pass this value properly and receive it back properly.

Comment: Even though this isn't supposed to work, the D compiler shouldn't ever crash with an internal compiler error. Might want to submit a bug report.

Comment: I found I could update my dmd today via brew with `sudo brew update; sudo brew upgrade dmd`. Now that I have, that same patch of code returns `Error: Internal Compiler Error: unsupported type string` and then `Segmentation fault: 11` So, it looks like the compiler has fixed that bug now. Meanwhile, we have an answer below.

Comment: No it hasn't; there's still an internal compiler error, and then a segfault. Both of those should never happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass from D a C null-terminated string using `std.string.toStringz`. In the same fashion there is `std.string.fromStringz`:

```
extern (C++) immutable(char)* dfunc(const char* s) {
    import std.string;
    return toStringz(fromStringz(s) ~ "response");
}
```

And then the caller in C++

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
char *dfunc(const char *);
extern "C" int rt_init();
extern "C" int rt_term();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        const char *sTest = "request";
        rt_init();
        NSLog(@"Result=%s",dfunc(sTest));
        rt_term();

  return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: This almost worked. I had to change the input parameter to `const char* s`, and here's how I included it in XCode in my main.mm file: http://pastebin.com/9s1WAr2t (temporary pastebin) Perhaps you can improve your answer by showing how it's called in the C++ like I show in my temporary pastebin?

Comment: Done, but you could improve the answer yourself after what a reviewer could accept the changes. I even think that you have enough karma on S.O to edit an answer without the need of a 3rd party review.

Comment: I do, but was being polite to you. :) Also, you are more knowledgeable than me in this topic, I feel currently, and so thought you might say something like, "yes but..." and proceed to show me something I might have missed even when I find the answer. (That happens sometimes.)

Answer (score 2):

A D string is a struct with `char*` and a `size_t` length. This is incompatible with std::string

A common way to avoid that is to revert to C style API design where you pass the char* and a length around directly.

This also means you have to be careful about allocation and freeing as the D allocator is not directly compatible with C++ allocator and pointers in C++ memory are not scanned by D's garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked many times on SO. I think one of the best answers is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6405870/876497

Note: hands down, the answer is C-related, but it can be applied to C++ as well.

Comment: If you believe this question is a duplicate, then please flag it as such. Otherwise, please include the relevant parts of the link in the question itself; link-only answers are vulnerable to link rot.